# How to inject service in method?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom class:

```
class Global {
 public isMobileDevice() {
 }
}
```

So, I want to inject service class inside this method like:

```
public isMobileDevice(private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService): boolean {
    return true;
}
```

Because I Can not inject this service in constructor like this:

```
constructor(private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService) {
}
```

I tried this:

```
public isMobileDevice(): boolean {
    return new DeviceDetectorService();
 }
```

Comment: `Because I Can not inject this service in constructor like this` why????

Comment: So far as i know, `angular` only supports constructor injection.

Comment: Because there are a lot of places where I use instance Global, and I dont want pass instance `DeviceDetectorService` in each places.

Comment: Is this your first time creating a service in Angular? Are you asking how DI works?

Comment: No, it is another case, my file Global is already as service, But I want to use `DeviceDetectorService` as static or as Facade

Comment: @OPV if your global class is already a service, then simply inject the dependency in the constructor ...

Comment: Please update your question so that others can understand what is being asked.

Comment: Angular DI injects only into the constructor of classes.

Comment: his question is simple, not sure why he is being bashed haha ..his class is not a angular component !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid injecting the service in your components' constructor by using static functions on a class that you plan to import where you want to use it instead of an angular service.

```ts
export class Global {
 public static isMobileDevice() {
 }
}
```

then, you use it like so:

```ts
import { Global } from '<path_to_global>';

class SomeComponent {
  isMobile = Global.isMobileDevice();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inject the service without constructor you could create a static method in your `module` class like this.

```
export class GlobalModule {

    static injector: Injector;
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        GlobalModule.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

With the `injector` class you can get `DeviceDetectorService`

```
public isMobileDevice(): boolean {
    var deviceDetectorService = GlobalModule.injector.get(DeviceDetectorService);
    // Logic 
}
```

Make sure that the `injector` property is set in an early stage of your application.